# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception -> installshield

Tags: c#, installshield

I build a winfom desktop application (Visual studio 2013, c#, Mssql, Entity framework 6).
If I test application in VS2013 is running fine, but I make installshield package and install it. Drop this exception:

```
Application: myprog.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(System.Data.Entity.Internal.IInternalConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(System.String)
   at myprog.Form1..ctor()
   at myprog.Program.Main()
```

What caused this?

The not generated code is all, not drop exception:

```
try
            {
                src.DataSource = valinor.vats.Select(m => m).ToList();
                vatGridControl.DataSource = src;
            }   
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: are you sure the computer have .NET 4.5? it seem to be .net 4.5 is missing?!

Comment: Isn't the error clear? `DbContext` constructor is throwing the exception. Wrap it in try/catch then log it to see what is the error message.That may give some idea

Comment: The computer have .net 4. This project with entity framework 5, worked fine.

Comment: DbContext generated the visual studio. How can I debug?

Comment: I tried install oneclick applcation. Working well.

Comment: Are you installing on a test computer with Installshield, or are you running on the same machine as VS2013?